# how to fix the csv ouput when using pandas and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Well I have a simple csv, that has 2 columns and about 50 rows.

The first column is ip and other is cik, and I want to get how many ip's are there with the different cik. So this is my code that does that, and it work great:

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
df = df.groupby('cik').count()
df = pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

But the csv output is like:

```
ip
49
```

And I want it to be like when I print the df value after groupby and count, something like this:

[image]

So I have in the first column the cik and in other the number of ip's that have that cik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option `index=False` makes the method omit row names which in your case is the `1515671`, save it with simple:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, did know the index = False impact the 'cik' column.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding reset_index before you output to_csv.

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
df = df.groupby('cik').count().reset_index()   #reset_index creates 0...n index and avoids cik as index
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

OR
set the `index=True` while outputting to_csv

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Or just use `as_index=False` in the groupby, or give the `to_csv()` the instruction to keep the index `index=True`

Comment: Thanks for your help !